# What is the difference in C# between the class being inside the namespace brackets and just stating the namespace in the same file?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Is there a difference between:

```
namespace Project.Location 
{
   public class ExampleClass 
   {
      // class stuff ...
   }
}
```

---- and --------------------------------------------

```
namespace Project.Location;

public class ExampleClass 
{
    // class stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Just a syntax sugar that avoids more nested code, it works the same way. By the way, I prefer the second one. Microsoft official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces

Answer (score 3):

[File-scoped namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces) were added in C# 10, and your examples are functionally equivalent. Before C# 10, the second example was not valid syntax - namespaces had to have scoping brackets (`{}`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in you examples.
The compiled code is equivalent.

It's a feature called

> File Scoped Namespaces

and it is available since C# 10

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces

```
namespace Project.Location 
{
   public class ExampleClass 
   {
      // class stuff ...
   }
}
```

is equivalent to writing

```
namespace Project.Location;

public class ExampleClass 
{
    // class stuff ...
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. You have basically copied the original post and added a link to content that may eventually disappear. How about actually explaining what it is, what it does and its limitations?

Comment: @JuanR thank you for your consideration. However the question is "what is the difference." And there is none.The compiled code is equivalent. And that's why i think the answer perfectly addresses the question.

Comment: The your answer should be "there is no difference and here is why...". Right now, it reads "It's called File Scoped Namespaces and it is available since C#10".

Comment: @JuanR i updated the answer. Hope it is better now

Answer (score 0):

When a file includes just one namespace you can use a NameSpace without {}.
Actually, in most cases, we use a single NameSpace for each file so this method simplifies our files and we'll have more space on our monitor to code.

Note: It is available after C# 10.

Answer (score -2):

There is a difference between the two codes. The first code defines a namespace Project.Location and declares a public class ExampleClass within that namespace. This is the usual way of organizing your code within namespaces, and it's the correct syntax in C#. The class ExampleClass is part of the Project.Location namespace.

```
namespace Project.Location 
{
   public class ExampleClass 
   {
      // class stuff ...
   }
}
```

The second code doesn't define a namespace and it directly declares a public class ExampleClass outside of any namespace. While this is syntactically valid, it means that ExampleClass is not within any specific namespace.

```
namespace Project.Location;

public class ExampleClass 
{
    // class stuff ...
}
```

It's good practice to use namespaces to organize your code and avoid naming conflicts in larger projects. The first code with the namespace declaration is the preferred approach.

Comment: This is clearly wrong. The 2nd code defines a namespace.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is wrong. I suggest you read up on File Scoped Namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I appreciate your input. My explanation was based on the context of C# and its namespace conventions. I should have clarified that the code snippets were interpreted in the context of C#. I'm glad you brought up 'File Scoped Namespaces' in C++, which is a valid consideration. It's a good reminder that programming languages have their own nuances. Thanks again for adding to the discussion!